# Adding Image for an array of annotations

Tags: swift, annotations

In the code below I was using an array of dictionaries to store the annotations. And using the for-loop function to display them. It worked in the beginning until after I attempted to change the image of the annotations. I would like to ask whether there is problem with my code and how can I add image to every annotations ?

I have searched for changing image for the annotations but it seems it didn't work.

```swift
    extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            if annotation is MKUserLocation {
                return nil
            }
             else {
                let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "annotationView") ?? MKAnnotationView()
                annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "bball")
                return annotationView
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my code

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation 

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
     //Annotation
     let pinlocations = [

        ["title" : "Blake Gardens","Subtitle" : "Opening Hours 7:30am - 10:00pm" ,"Latitude" : 22.284030 , "Longtitude" : 114.148760 ],

        ["title" : "Kennedy Road Playground","Subtitle" : "Opening Hours 7:00am - 11:00pm" ,"Latitude": 22.274700, "Longtitude" : 114.165940 ],

        ["title" : "Kennedy Town Playground","Subtitle" : "Opening Hours 7:00am - 11:00pm" ,"Latitude": 22.274714, "Longtitude" : 114.155901 ],

        ["title" : "Kennedy Town Service Reservoir Playground", "Subtitle" : "Opening Hours 7:00am - 11:00pm", "Latitude": 22.281910, "Longtitude" : 114.123200 ],

        ["title" : "Kennedy Town Temporary Recreation Ground ","Subtitle" : "Opening Hours 7:00am - 11:00pm" ,"Latitude": 22.281430, "Longtitude" : 114.121070],

        ["title" : "Li Sing Street Playground ","Subtitle" : "Opening Hours 7:00am - 10:00pm" ,"Latitude": 22.286980, "Longtitude" : 114.145430 ],

        ["title" : " Pok Fu Lam Road Playground ", "Subtitle" : "Opening Hours 7:00am - 11:00pm" ,"Latitude": 22.281220, "Longtitude" : 114.130440 ],

        ["title" : "Third Street Playground", "Subtitle" : "Opening Hours 8:00am - 10:00pm" ,"Latitude": 22.288031, "Longtitude" : 114.140831 ]
    ]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createAnnotations(locations: pinlocations)
    }
    func createAnnotations(locations :[[String : Any]]) {
        for locations in locations {
            let annotations = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotations.title = locations["title"] as! String
            annotations.subtitle = locations["Subtitle"] as! String
            annotations.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locations["Latitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees , longitude: locations["Longtitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "It worked in the beginning until after I attempted to change the image of the annotations." <--- How did it not work?

Comment: Your `createAnnotations` doesn't seem to do anything useful. It doesn't actually add the annotations to the map.

Comment: Right, someone told me I missed `mapView.addAnnotation(annotations)` . But do you know how to create images for my arrays of annotations ? I have tried like the above but still can't figure out how .